# generated folder should be read-only file system? - Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, file-permissions, cloud

I upgraded from **Magento 2.1.11** to **Magento 2.2.2**. I have one critical issue that is most our extensions complain about **generated** folder is a read-only file system. Magento team strongly recommend **generated** folder should be read-only in Magento 2.2.2.

where would be third-party extensions **generation** contents are placed in Magento 2.2.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

> To update components, install new components, or to upgrade the Magento software, all of the preceding directories must be read-write.

So during upgrade and compile and static deploy they of course need write permission but after those are done you can remove the write permission and restore write only when you are upgrading again.